# Android adapter pass JSON object data?

Tags: java, android, json

Very new to java and android, but I think I need a layout inflater, I tried to implement it but failed, I erased that code.

I can turn the object into an array of strings and use an `ArrayAdapter` to loop the layout assigning the strings to a `textView`

So `ArrayAdapter` is limited

```
ListAdapter dribbbleFeedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.feed_card, R.id.info_text, titleArr);
```

I can only pass in the context, layout, textView, and array of strings.

What I want to do is pass the image and other data into the views of that layout. So my question is how do I build the adapter so that I can assign values from the object to the view id?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // GET Json and use adapter ListView
    Ion.with(this)
            .load("http://api.dribbble.com/shots/everyone")
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {

                // SET Titles Array
                List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

                // BUILD THE ARRAY
                JsonArray shots = result.getAsJsonArray("shots");
                for (int i = 0; i < shots.size(); i++) {
                  String title = shots.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("title").getAsString();
                  titles.add(title);
                }
                String[] titleArr = new String[titles.size()];
                titleArr = titles.toArray(titleArr);

                // TODO: Put more data into the feed_card
                //dribbbleImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_1);
                ListAdapter dribbbleFeedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.feed_card, R.id.info_text, titleArr);
                ListView dribbbleDataListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dribbbleFeedListView);
                dribbbleDataListView.setAdapter(dribbbleFeedAdapter);
              }
            });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your own Adapter extends BaseAdapter.

Just like the code below:

```
public class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public TestAdapter(Context context, List<Data> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    private List<Data> dataList;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dataList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout.your_list_item_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new View();
            holder.tv_title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.iv_data = convertView.findViewById(R.id.data);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Data data = dataList.get(position);
        holder.tv_title.setText(data.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_title;
        ImageView iv_data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that sounds right, but I am still trying to figure out how I can use objects to populate the view, so some examples or hints would be great.